# Why is Core Location manager not working on iOS 6 simulator (using OSX Mountain Lion)

Tags: ios, ios6, core-location, cllocationmanager, simulator

I was following the Core Data tutorial for iOS from this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1)
and my location manager does not appear to be picking up any events.  I enabled location services on the simulator and when I launch the app it asks for permission to use my location and I say "ok".  Any idea why it's not picking anything up?

My location manager delegate method shown below returns the following error:

> 2013-02-15 18:05:16.653 Locations[8280:c07] errorError Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

I even tried Debug --> simulate location.
I am using OSX Mountain Lion btw.

Thanks!

```
//location manager delegate method for fail
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Reached loc mngr delegate method 2...error occurred");
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"error%@",error);
    switch([error code])
    {
        case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"please check your network connection or that you are not in airplane mode" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        case kCLErrorDenied:{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"user has denied to use current Location " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        default:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"unknown network error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
    }
    addButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Are implementing `locationManager:DidFailwithError:`?

Comment: I see this particular error if my simulator's "debug" -> "location" is set to "none". If I set the simulator to any real location, I don't see that error. What is your simulator's location setting now set to? Have you tried it on a device?

Comment: How can you be using an iOS 6 simulator with OS X Mountain Lion? Are you using iOS or OS X?

Comment: It didn't seem to have a setting selected under "debug" --> "location".  So I clicked on Tokyo, nothing happened.  Then I clicked on another place, still nothing happened. I did end up trying it on a device and the location manager appears to be working.  But I wonder why not on the simulator.  But at least it works on the device! Mike: yep i'm implementing DidFailwithError (see posted code above).  rdelmar: I mean on my mac which has OSX Mountain Lion, I was running the simulator in XCode for iPhone 6.1 Simulator.